# code-push: How to find deployment keys for the app added from appcenter website ( add new app option )

Tags: code-push, react-native-code-push

I added a react-native android app using the **Add new app** option on appcenter website.
Now i need to find the deployment keys for the same.
I tried
 ***code-push deployment list  YourAppName --displayKeys***
but it didnt return keys.

Although when I add the app using CLI
     ***code-push app add YourAppName  android react-native***
and then retrieve the keys using earlier command it works fine and gives both staging and pro keys.

Please somebody explain this.

Thanks.

Comment: i got the solution :

Answer (score 6):

this worked -

**appcenter codepush deployment add -a {User_Name}/{App_Name} Production**

**appcenter codepush deployment add -a {User_Name}/{App_Name} Staging**

Note : Make sure appcenter is installed ( ***sudo npm instal -g appcenter-cli*** )

Comment: This is a necessary setup in the walkthrough guide, I don't know why this is not included in the docs for setting up codepush.

Answer (score 2):

`appcenter codepush deployment list -a username/appname --displayKeys` works for me